# Return url of localhost in laravel using transbank

Tags: php, laravel

I am totally new to laravel, I have been creating a project to pay with transbank, everything is fine, but when I return my url I can't find my localhost path.

Laravel's artisan server starts with`php artisan serve --host=my-ip-address --port:8000` I really don't know what happens.

Do I occupy windows, do I have to install any configuration? or while this environment should be done on a server like Xampp and do some configuration? I am super lost, my return url in laravel I leave it like this in the browser.

```
http://my-ip-address:8000/initPay
```

So it starts, it goes to the transbank page and everything is fine, but when returning the url that I specify in the method it does not work.

my code laravel

web routes

```
Route::get('/initPay', 'WebPayPlussController@initPayWeb');
Route::post('/confirm_pay', 'WebPayPlussController@confirmPay');
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Transbank\Webpay\WebpayPlus;
use Transbank\Webpay\WebpayPlus\Transaction;

class WebPayPlussController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(){
        WebpayPlus::configureForIntegration('597055555532', '579B532A7440BB0C9079DED94D31EA1615BACEB56610332264630D42D0A36B1C');
    }

    public function initPayWeb(Request $request){

        $buy_order ='abc456';
        $session_id='4784568';
        $amount=10000;
        $response = (new Transaction)->create(
            $buy_order, 
            $session_id, 
            $amount,
            'http://my-ip-address:8000/confirm_pay');

        $url =$response->getUrl().'?token_ws='.$response->getToken();
        return redirect()->away($url);
        
    }

    public function confirmPay(Request $request){
       
        $confirm=  (new Transaction)->commit($request->get('token_ws'));

        if($confirmacion->isApproved()){
            return 'is Approved';
        }else{
            return 'is not Approved';
        }
       

      
    }

    
}

Please, if someone can guide me more on the subject or how to make it return to the localhost url, I would really appreciate it, I searched and I am still lost..
```

Comment: This is likely supposed to be a "callback URL", meaning it does not get visited in the user's browser, but their servers will make a request to yours. So your URL needs to be publicly reachable. (ngrok is a popular service to create an HTTPS tunnel to your machine that is reachable from outside, for testing purposes.)

Comment: Thank you very much, you do not know how much you have helped me! Thank you just what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route `/confirm_pay` will definitely not work with a private IP address... which isn't route-able.

You would need to deploy that script to a server with a publicly available IP address.

`ngrok` might be a possible workaround, but a rather cumbersome one.